# Mysql bug, ghost column

Tags: mysql, database

I delete a column in mysql called "clanName" and i see this:

[image: Photo]

I can't edit it, and that column doesn't exists.

I restart mysql and Xampp and continue...

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you delete it?

Comment: In the structure panel, i press "Delete"

Comment: Maybe a phpmyadmin bug,try another client like heidisql.

Comment: I will not change the database, I do not send querys generated problems, so here I leave as well. (Google traductor, i'm spanish)

Comment: Can you access the DB with a desktop client like (if on OS X) [Sequel Pro](http://sequelpro.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tab called 'Operations.' Click on that tab and duplicate this table. There is an excellent chance that your duplicated version will no longer contain the empty column.

If this works, you can then rename the original version by appending the word 'BACKUP' to the name. Then rename your newly duplicated copy to the original table's name and test. If everything works with your project, you may wish to delete the old (and broken!) backup copy.

Good luck, please let me know if this works for you. If it does not please export a copy of the database table and post it here on StackOverflow. I will be happy to examine it further.

Comment: I solve the "bug" creating a new column, this repleace the old and bugged column :), but Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much!  I am really glad you have been successful. Please feel free to let me know if you need any other help.